# boxTidwell - 'NA' Handling

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

My data frame is

```
library(car)
DF2 <- data.frame(WindVel=c(2.45,2.7,2.9,3.05,3.4,3.6,3.95,4.1,4.6,5),
                  DCOutput=c(0.123,0.5,0.653,0.558,1.057,1.137,1.144,NA,NA,NA))
```

Later I want to perform Box-Tidwell transformation on the data frame by excluding NA's. Hence I used:

```
boxTidwell(DF2$DCOutput, DF2$WindVel, options(na.action="na.exclude"))
```

This gives a error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ cbind(x1, x2),  drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'cbind(x1, x2)'
```

I tried:

```
boxTidwell(DF2$DCOutput, DF2$WindVel, na.action=na.exclude)
```

However, it does not work as well. Please let me know how to exclude the NA's while using `boxTidwell`. I could not understand much from the user manual of the `car` package related to the usage with NA's.

Comment: you can use ` DF3=na.omit(DF2);  boxTidwell(DF3$DCOutput,DF3$WindVel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use the formula method for `boxTidwell`. From `?boxTidwell`:

```
## S3 method for class 'formula'
boxTidwell(formula, other.x=NULL, data=NULL, subset, 
  na.action=getOption("na.action"), verbose=FALSE, tol=0.001, 
  max.iter=25, ...)

na.action:  a function that indicates what should happen when the data contain NAs. The default is set by the na.action setting of options.
```

Since the out-of-the-box value of the `na.action` option is `na.omit`, you'll get a complete-case analysis, as you would from `na.exclude`.

In your case, you could use

```
boxTidwell(WindVel ~ DCOutput,  data=DF2, na.action = na.exclude)
```

This pattern of arguments is common to statistical modeling functions that use the formula interface.

John